# How could I use a WHERE in an EXISTS() in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find all path in a graph between two nodes, with the condition that any node in this path must be connected to another node with a label TIMESWITCH and valid endDate and startDate.

The purpose of the TIMESWITCH nodes is to indicate that the connected node can be used only for certain time ranges.

So I used this Cypher query :

```
MATCH  p=(:MYNODE {myid:'node1'}) -[*]- (:MYNODE {myid:'node2'}) 
WHERE  ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE EXISTS(
           (n)<--(ts:TIMESWITCH) 
           WHERE ts.startDate < datetime("2018-10-01T00:00:00") <= ts.endDate ))
RETURN p
```

But this query is incorrect because the WHERE clause is forbidden inside an EXISTS. That simply means that inside an exists, one can test equality but not inequality.

So I don't know what to do ... how am I supposed to write that exists ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a pattern comprehension as a workaround, as pattern comprehensions allow you to introduce new variables for the comprehension and filter with a WHERE clause. You'll just need to check the size of the comprehension to ensure it's not empty.

```
MATCH  p=(:MYNODE {myid:'node1'}) -[*]- (:MYNODE {myid:'node2'}) 
WHERE  ALL(n in nodes(p) WHERE size([(n)<--(ts:TIMESWITCH) 
   WHERE ts.startDate < datetime("2018-10-01T00:00:00") <= ts.endDate | ts]) > 0)
RETURN p
```

Comment: Thank it worked great ! I did not know about pattern comprehension but it is awsome.

Comment: Glad to help! Here's the [documentation link](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension).